# Real-time data collection and 'offline' processing

Tags: python, read-write, data-stream

I have a continuous stream of data. I want to do a small amount of processing to the data in real-time (mostly just compression, rolling some data off the end, whatever needs doing) and then store the data. Presumably no problem. HDF5 file format should do great! OOC data, no problem. Pytables.

Now the trouble. Occasionally, as a completely separate process so that data is still being gathered, I would like to perform a time consuming calculation involving the data (order minutes). This involving reading the same file I'm writing.

How do people do this?

Of course reading a file that you're currently writing should be challenging, but it seems that it must have come up enough in the past that people have considering some sort of slick solution---or at least a natural work-around.

Partial solutions:

1. It seems that HDF5-1.10.0 has a capability SWMR - Single Write, Multiple Read. This seems like exactly what I want. I can't find a python wrapper for this recent version, or if it exists I can't get Python to talk to the right version of hdf5. Any tips here would be welcomed. I'm using Conda package manager.
2. I could imagine writing to a buffer, which is occasionally flushed and added to the large database. How do I ensure that I'm not missing data going by while doing this?

This also seems like it might be computationally expensive, but perhaps there's no getting around that.

3. Collect less data. What's the fun in that?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at adding [`Apache Kafka`](http://kafka.apache.org/) to your pipeline, it can act as a data buffer and help you separate different tasks done on the data you collect.

pipeline example:

raw data ===> kafka topic (raw_data) ===> small processing ====> kafak topic (light_processing)  ===> a process read from `light_processing` topic and writes to db or file

At the same time you can read with another process the same data from `light_processing topic` or any other topic and do your heavy processing and so on.

if both the `light processing` and the `heavy processing` connect to kafka topic with the same groupId the data will be replicated and both processes will get the same stream

hope it helped.